# Reading Perl error

Tags: oracle, apache, perl, oracle11g, environment-variables

I havent been able to find a decent answer to this question: How to read (interpret) Perl errors. I have the following error

> can't load /auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so for module DBD::Oracle
>   libclntsh.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory at
>   packages/perl/perl-5.8.8/lib/5.8.8/i686-linux-thread-multi/somefile.pm
>   line #

1. What I would like to know is how do I understand what the error is saying? I understand that there is an Oracle installation at the auto/DBD/Oracle directory and perl cant load the DBD::Oracle module but what does the first ':' mean in the second line of the error? Is it two errors that I am reading? If not what is the relation of the first line and the second and third lines of the same error?
2. I have found the path to the Oracle module and can confirm that there is indeed an Oracle.so file. I have confirmed that the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH correctly leads to the Oracle installation. So why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

```
 can't load /auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so for module DBD::Oracle libclntsh.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file No such file or directory at packages/perl/perl-5.8.8/lib/5.8.8/i686-linux-thread-multi/somefile.pm
```

This says that it was trying to load the DBD::Oracle runtime library, and in the process tried to load  libclntsh.so.10.1 which it could not open, because it isn;t in the expected directory.

if you have `locate` on your machine you can run 
    $ locate libclntsh.so.10.1

and see what you get back.  If you get an error, you can try find:

```
$ sudo find / -name libclntsh.so.10.1 -print | less
```